# What is this OST in the 1st season of My Hero Academia?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

In the the episode 10 of the 1st season of *My Hero Academia*, the music starts around 15:00 (more precisely at 14:53). It is also available in episode 9 of season 3 at 15:47.

What is this song?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of this OST is *Mind of Evil*. This OST is by Yuki HAYASHI and can be found in the track 27 ([YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlNauHj2z48)) of *My Hero Academia Original Soundtrack*.